# Pandas group by consecutive numbers

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm dealing with a DataFrame like this:

```
n_days    probability
 0            0.01
 17           0.1
 18           0.11
 19           0.12
 40           0.2
 41           0.21
```

I want to group consecutive numbers and get the mean probability of each group, like this:

```
n_days     mean_probability
  0           0.01
 17-19        0.11
 40-41        0.205
```

Formatting on the `n_days` isn't too relevant.

I tried something like:

```
df['diff_days'] = df.n_days - df.n_days.shift()
```

And then:

```
df.diff_days.eq(1)
```

Which brings this boolean:

```
n_days    probability   bool_eq
 0            0.01       False
 17           0.1        False
 18           0.11       True
 19           0.12       True       
 40           0.2        False
 41           0.21       True
```

Which seems to be a step forward, but I'm not sure how to follow up. Each `False` would be the start of each group, but how would I catch the whole group?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group on [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) bins.  Note that each bin is from but excluding the first value to and including the last value, e.g. (16-19] is equivalent to [17-19] where the column consists of integers.

```
bins = [-1, 0, 16, 19, 39, 41]
>>> df.groupby(
        pd.cut(df['n_days'], bins))['probability'].mean().dropna()
n_days
(-1, 0]     0.010
(16, 19]    0.110
(39, 41]    0.205
Name: probability, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I feel I should have known about `pd.cut` after all this time. Thanks @Alexander, because the dataframe's bigger I went with `bins = df[df.bool_eq==0].n_days.tolist()`, then
`bins = [-1,*bins]` and finally
`mean_probability=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.n_days,bins)).probability.mean() `

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
mean_probability=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.n_days,len(df)//2)).probability.mean()
```

---

```
n_days
(-0.041, 13.667]    0.010
(13.667, 27.333]    0.110
(27.333, 41.0]      0.205
Name: probability, dtype: float64
```